# Java 8 How to kick off a thread just before returning of a method

Tags: spring, multithreading, java-8

I have a service written in Java Spring. This service is to return a computational result to the user. However, I also want to do some additional task (a side task) with that result and it should not affect the performance. So my question is how can I kick off another Thread to do the additional task without preventing returning the result back to the user.

Comment: Spin an `Async` service in your service when result is ready?

Comment: How? I know it has to be an async. Just don't know how.

Comment: create a new service that your service will use. Once the result is ready, before returning it from the method, invoke the other service: `otherService.execute(result); return result;`. This `OtherSetvice::execute` is annotated with `@Async` - there millions of google searches on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your additional task using a `Runnable`. Then submit it to an executor service like so,

```
String response = invokeEp();
Runnable task = () -> doSomeWork(response);
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.submit(task);
return response;
```